# Can using inline lower performance?

Tags: performance, function, inline

Can making function inline in some specific cases lower the overall performance of application?

Comment: WHat language? What specific cases?

Comment: It's more of a general question, I guess I should post it on Stack Exchange.Programmers, my mistake...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inlining (particularly large functions) can increase the code size so that cache performance is affected and overall performance decreases.

Answer (score 1):

Inlining works with every language that supports it.

The functions that deserve inlining are usually short and simple, it's unuseful to inline long and complicated functions, but things like property getter or functions that performs some arithmetical calculations gets a lot of performance boost when inlined.

In languages like C and C++ the compiler choose the best inline strategy for your method when you specify inline keyword, a function marked inline is "recommended for inlining", but is the compiler that choose if is the case to inline for real or not.
However you should put the inline keyword only when the function deserves inlining for real.

Some C and C++ compilers supports special keywords like __forceinline or some other special attributes that say to the compiler "this is very recommended for inlining" and these keywords should be used with caution, since inlining big and complicated functions can lower down performances.